# SSD performance benefit in OLTP vs OLAP

Tags: olap, solid-state-drive, oltp

In which system is SSD disk better over HDD as far as performance is concerned ? An OLTP or an OLAP system ?

My guess is that in OLTP an SSD disk is more valuable, because transactions are constantly occurring and we need the non-sequential read-write speeds. Is this correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not experienced with the two systems, but from what I know I would say that an SSD would be most beneficent for a OLTP system. Since OLAP is focused more upon complex queries involving aggregation, I'd be inclined to think that read-write times would not be the limiting factor for an OLAP system. That's my two-cents.

You can read more [here](http://datawarehouse4u.info/OLTP-vs-OLAP.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is what I suspected as well